# Erro ao separar as responsabilidades

Tags: javascript, node.js, ddd, sequelize-js

No node, criei o seguinte modelo para representar meu usuário:

```js
"use strict";

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function() {
  return sequelize.define('user', {
    ID_USER: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    Name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'NAME',
 allowNull : true
  },
 Email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'EMAIL',
 allowNull : true
  },
 Photo: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'PHOTO',
 allowNull : true
  },
 Password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      field: 'PASSWORD',
   allowNull : true
 },
    Country: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
   field: 'COUNTRY',
    },
    State: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
   field: 'STATE',
    },
    City: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
   field: 'CITY',
    },
    AddDate: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      allowNull: true,
   defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
   field: 'ADD_DATE'
    }
  }, {
 createdAt: false,
 updatedAt: false,
    tableName: 'user'
})};
```

E na minha aplicação principal eu criei o seguinte código:

```js
var User = require('./User');

var Sequelize = require('sequelize')
  , sequelize = new Sequelize('uri', 'root', 'tibia+_.0017', {
      dialect: "mariadb", 
      port:    3306, 
    });

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(function(err) {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  }, function (err) { 
    console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });
  

var bruno = new User({ 
  Name: 'Bruno',
  Email: 'brunoj.santos91@gmail.com',
  Photo : 'teste',
  Password: 'cliente1234',
  Country: 'Brazil',
  State: 'SP',
  City: 'São Paulo'});

  
bruno.create({
  }).then(function(user) {
    res.json(user);
  });
```

Quando executo o ficheiro principal tem o seguinte erro:

> sequelize is not defined

Minha pergunta está além do erro, é como faço para separar o projeto em várias camadas, porque no meu projeto ainda não consigo remover a conexão com o modelo.Minha ideia seria ter os seguintes arquivos:

Arquivo de conexão.
Arquivo que representa o modelo do objeto (aqui vou ter vários arquivos)
Arquivo que executa o CRUD.

Seria basicamente uma estrutura DDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O primeiro problema é que o `sequelize` que vc deve usar ao definir os modelos é a **instância configurada** com o banco e não a classe estática.

Exemplo:

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize') // evite misturar as definições estáticas das dinâmicas

const sequelize = new Sequelize('uri', 'root', 'tibia+_.0017', {
  dialect: "mariadb", 
  port:    3306, 
})

sequelize.authenticate()
.then(authenticatedSequelize => {
    
    authenticatedSequelize.define('user', {
        ID_USER: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        ...
    })

})
```

Porém isso não resolve o seu outro problema que é a modularização. Sugiro a seguinte configuração:

> root/
>
> - models/
>
>   - configureDatabase.js
>   - index.js
>   - user.js

Sendo o **configureDatabase.js** a configuração do banco:

```
// evite misturar as definições estáticas com as dinâmicas
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

module.exports = () => {
    const sequelize = new Sequelize('uri', 'root', 'tibia+_.0017', {
        dialect: "mariadb", 
        port:    3306, 
    })
    return sequelize.authenticate() // é aqui que gera o authenticatedSequelize
}
```

Sendo dentro dos modelos (**user.js**):

```
module.exports = (authenticatedSequelize) => {
  return authenticatedSequelize.define('user', {
        ID_USER: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        ...
    })
}
```

E assim, no **index.js**:

```js
const configureDatabase = require('./configureDatabase')
const userModel = require('./user')

exports.load = () => {

  return configureDatabase() // faz a configuração do banco com seus parâmetros
  .then(authenticatedSequelize => {

    // é aqui que entrega a instância para os modelos
    exports.User = userModel(authenticatedSequelize)

    return
  }
}
```

Concluindo, para usar seus modelos bastará fazer:

```
const models = require('./models')
models.load()
.then(() => {
    return models.User.findAll()
})
```

Comment: A parte :

return authenticatedSequelize.define( **tararã** )

Seria o objeto passado por parâmetro ?

O configureDatabase deu erro "Cannot read property 'define'", ai eu não  entendi muito bem sendo que eu chamei o sequelize

Comment: Substitui o _tararã_ pelo exemplo efetivo copiando do exemplo acima, pra ver se fica mais claro. Também descrevi literalmente o conteúdo do `configureDatabase.js` pra evitar esse erro.